# Terminal command with sudo takes a long time

Tags: command-line, sudo

I noticed that the terminal recently becomes too slow when I execute a command that needs my password. It takes some seconds to display [sudo] password for ...

I'm using Dell XPS developer edition (i7,8G RAM) with Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your terminal from the options displayed at the top of your terminal box when displayed?  I had a similar issue with this and corrected the slow down once I selected 'Reset' on the 'Terminal' option list.

Comment: It's very strange, but, I receive "Ubuntu could not resolve the host" when connection isn't available. I execute this command "echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
"

Comment: [serverfault: Why does sudo command take long to execute?](http://serverfault.com/questions/38114/why-does-sudo-command-take-long-to-execute)

Answer (score 156):

Hi I found this answer on another question - 
The problem is if your hostname is not in your hosts file.

basically, type  "hostname" in your terminal.  That will tell you what your hostname is.

Next, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and add:

```
127.0.0.1 yourhostname
```

then save - and you are done!
Sudo should be fast now!

Comment: This post I guess ? : http://serverfault.com/questions/38114/why-does-sudo-command-take-long-to-execute

Comment: I have the feeling that it can also be caused by DNS setting in NetworkManager: https://askubuntu.com/questions/898605/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-and-resolve-dns-with-dnsmasq

Comment: This is still valid in ubuntu 18.04. Thanks

Comment: @Paul Preibisch, I have the same issue in mac. How can i get the host name?

Comment: Can there be another reason? Because I do have my hostname in /etc/hosts and it takes 25 seconds for the password prompt to appear. Makes productive work impossible.

Comment: Works like a charm -- in my case, I had changed the name of my machine and did not modify the name in the hosts file

Answer (score 16):

When you change your systems name in Gnome (The part that is displayed in the terminal after the @; e.g. `tobias@laptop` to `tobias@newlaptop` you might need to update your `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1 laptop
```

needs to be changed to

```
127.0.1.1 newlaptop
```

If you get it right `sudo` should work without delay immediately after saving this setting.

Answer (score 11):

**Answer 1**
Confirmed @Paul Preibisch answer for those who want more detailed answer

I had this issue for a long time and all I did was to run

`hostnamectl | grep -i "static hostname"`

this will show you your hostname then copy the value and edit your hosts

`sudo vim /etc/hosts`

and add `127.0.0.1 yourHostName` to it
also in some distros `127.0.1.1 yourHostName` should be replaced

---

**Answer 2**
Please note that in many cases the `answer 1` will solve your problem if it didn't you have to check your `sudo` log which in debian based distros is under
`/var/log/auth.log`
so you can watch your sudo log with tail command
`sudo tail -f -n 100 /var/log/auth.log`
then open another terminal and run a sudo command like:
`sudo ls /`
go back to your first terminal and read the log, in my case the problem was due to `pam_krb5` authentication failure the log was:
`sudo: pam_krb5(sudo:auth): authentication failure;`
after I removed it sudo command worked instantly...

Thanks to @gdm for giving the clue...

Comment: This is the best, elegant and most valuable response to the question.

Comment: Running `hostnamectl`, I get "Failed to query system properties: Connection timed out". The hostname returned by `hostname` already has a 127.0.0.1 entry in /etc/hosts, but the problem persists.

Comment: By far the best response

Comment: it not works in centos, or rather this is not the only cause

Comment: @gdm probably! I had same issue like you but I couldn't figure it out so finally I reinstalled my os.

Comment: best to see first log of your os, like /var/log/messages or /var/log/audit.log. I discovered that there was a call to the fingerprint daemon every time I used su. So I disabled it 
``authconfig --disablefingerprint --update``

Answer (score 4):

For the lazy - Just copy paste this in your terminal :)

```
echo -e '127.0.0.1\t' $(hostnamectl | grep -i "static hostname:" | cut -f2- -d:) | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

sudo should be fast after you run this

Edit - Explaining this command in more detail:

- It first grabs your localhost cutting the label string ahead (hostnamectl | grep -i "static hostname:" | cut -f2- -d:) e.g. *mylocalhost*
- It concatenates it with *127.0.0.1* ahead ("\t" means tab character)
- It take the full string created above (*127.0.0.1        mylocalhost*) and adds it to the end of /etc/hosts (you need sudo to edit the hosts file)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Would be nice to explain what that line does - it’s always a bad idea to copy text into the terminal without understanding what it’s doing. Thank you.

Comment: @Will I just edited my comment to add more detail