# How to disable systemd-resolved and resolve DNS with dnsmasq?

Tags: 16.10, dns, dnsmasq, 17.04, systemd-resolved

Ubuntu 16.10+ uses `systemd-resolved` as DNS resolver.

I prefer the setup 16.04 uses, `dnsmasq` as the resolver.

How can I do that on 16.10+, especially on 17.04?

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032450/add-dnsmasq-for-cached-fast-resolution-and-keep-systemd-resolved-18-04

Comment: Why we need a resolver... Why not simply use `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8` as resolver...

Comment: @recolic caching, prevent some records from being resolved (ads, trackers etc), defining new top-level-domains for your own records, *speed*

Answer (score 59):

`dnsmasq` packages are still available in 16.10 and 17.04.

1. **Install `dnsmasq` and dependencies** (or at least download their packages) ***before* disabling `systemd-resolved`**:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
   ```
2. Disable `systemd-resolved` and verify `dnsmasq` is running:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
   sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved

   systemctl status dnsmasq
   ```
3. Season `dnsmasq` to taste.  After applying your settings, restart `dnsmasq`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq
   sudo systemctl start dnsmasq
   ```

After step 2 you might be without a working system resolver until step 3 is complete.  You may need to restart the networking subsystem (or simply reboot) to get `dnsmasq` functioning with the default configs.  In my testing, adding a known DNS server to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and restarting `dnsmasq` was enough to get it working in a liveCD environment.

Comment: Great answer,  and seemingly the only solution when disabling NetworkManager is not acceptable!

Comment: For me, this was a great answer but also required the additional steps from @blabla's answer, adding `dns=dnsmasq` config to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: Same here. After struggling with systemd-resolved and unbound switching to dnsmasq did the trick on ubuntu 17.10. I did have to use blabla's additions though.

Comment: After struggling with resolved for days, this did the trick. TYVM

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the answer of @quixotic:

Make sure you have in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf :

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

if you need to add it, restart NetworkManager like this:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

and `/etc/resolv.conf` needs to be a symlink to `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` . could be done like this

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf; sudo ln -s /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Actually I have it set as `dns=default` and it works fine because I have the nameservers defined then by NetworkManager instead of being defined in dnsmasq; this works for me - NM gets the nameservers from the settings made in KDE's NM configuration via the system tray. I use fixed IP on my home network FWIW.

Comment: This step was  a necessary addition to @quixotic's answer for me (ubuntu 17.04, full installation, not LiveCD).

Answer (score 4):

For (X)Ubuntu 18.04 (see my [answer at stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516808/351068)).

Here is copy of it (should I make a copy?)

Here is solution for (X)Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

Install dnsmasq

`sudo apt install dnsmasq`

Disable systemd-resolved listener on port 53 (do not touch /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, because it may be overwritten on upgrade):

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/noresolved.conf 
[Resolve]
DNSStubListener=no
```

and restart it

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

(alternatively disable it completely by `$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`)

Delete /etc/resolv.conf and create again. This is important, because resolv.conf is a symbolic link to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf by default. If you will not delete symbolic link, the file will be overwritten by systemd on reboot (even though we disabled systemd-resolved!). Also NetworkManager (NM) checks if it is a symbolic link to detect systemd-resolved configuration.

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo touch /etc/resolv.conf
```

Disable overwriting of /etc/resolv.conf by NM (there is also an option rc-manager, but it does not work, despite it is described in a manual):

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/disableresolv.conf 
[main]
dns=none
```

and restart it:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Tell dnsmasq to use resolv.conf from NM:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/nmresolv.conf 
resolv-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
```

and restart it:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

Use dnsmasq for resolving:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Use local dnsmasq for resolving
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual of [systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html), systemd-resolved provides with name resolution services via three different interfaces:

1. "fully-featured API systemd-resolved exposes on the bus"
2. "a local DNS stub listener on IP address 127.0.0.53 on the local loopback interface"
3. > The glibc getaddrinfo(3) API as defined by RFC3493 and its related resolver functions, including gethostbyname(3). This API is widely supported, including beyond the Linux platform. In its current form it does not expose DNSSEC validation status information however, and is synchronous only. This API is backed by the glibc Name Service Switch (nss(5)). Usage of the glibc NSS module nss-resolve(8) is required in order to allow glibc's NSS resolver functions to resolve host names via systemd-resolved.

It seems that the first two interfaces won't interfere in normal DNS resolution and for me the problem is likely to reside on the third.

In the manual of [nss-resolve](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-resolve.html#):

> To activate the NSS module, add "resolve" to the line starting with "hosts:" in /etc/nsswitch.conf. Specifically, it is recommended to place "resolve" early in /etc/nsswitch.conf's "hosts:" line (but after the "files" or "mymachines" entries), right before the "dns" entry if it exists, followed by "[!UNAVAIL=return]", to ensure DNS queries are always routed via systemd-resolved(8) if it is running, but are routed to nss-dns if this service is not available

So what is needed is to make "dns" precedes "resolve" in "host:" line of */etc/nsswitch.conf*. And then `getaddrinfo` should simply adhere to */etc/resolv.conf* .

This solution only prevents systemd-resolved from handling all the DNS resolution requests and is not restricted to a specific network manager. And it also makes sure LLMNR and mDNS service are operating normally.

( I am not fair familiar with how name resolution works under Linux and also unsure about what I understood from these manuals. Pleaes point out if I got something wrong. Thx :) )