# /etc/hosts file wiping edits after suspending or rebooting

Tags: networking, hosts

18.04 with latest updates.

I am trying to modify my `/etc/hosts` file so I can access my local server via its hostname.
I make the change with `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, and it sticks fine for the current session. However, after rebooting my system or suspending it, the file reverts itself back to the state it was in before I edited it.
I have attempted to edit using both the terminal in a graphical session as well as from a tty prompt on a fresh boot with no avail.
This has only started happening since a new router was installed in my homes network, however I cannot see why that would cause this issue.

```
$ ls -al /etc/hosts   
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 254 Jan 20 17:03 /etc/hosts
```

Comment: You might have something else changing it if it is not staying.  Are you changing the `/etc/hosts` file as sudo?  `/etc/hosts` is not a link file nor is it controlled by any daemons that I am aware of, so there shouldn't be any reason why it is changing between reboots.  What is the output of `ls -al /etc/hosts`?

Comment: Sorry, forget about the sudo part, I see it in your question. I am still very curious what the `ls -al /etc/hosts` outputs.  It should be a standalone file with a 644 permissions owned by root:root.

Comment: @Terrance, Added the output of that to the OP

Comment: Hmmmmm, that is so odd.  I wonder if `nano` might be creating a temp file that is not getting erased before reboot, then when a reboot happens, it takes the tmp file and overrides the one that was just changed?  I don't know for sure, but can you try adding a line to the bottom of your hosts file by trying `sudo bash -c 'echo "127.0.1.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts'` from a terminal window then reboot and see if that sticks?

Comment: @Terrance, I figured it out. Turns out there is no issue, I am just stupid. I just remembered that I have a script that changes the host file depending on if I am at home or out so I can access my server with either scenario. The new router means a new SSID which means that script is broken. Derp. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Glad that you figured it out!  =)

Answer (score 0):

The file is overwritten by [`systemd-resolved.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html), among other files:

> systemd-resolved synthesizes DNS resource records (RRs) for the
>   following cases:
>
> - The local, configured hostname is resolved to all locally configured IP addresses ordered by their scope, or — if none are configured — the
>     IPv4 address 127.0.0.2 (which is on the local loopback) and the IPv6
>     address ::1 (which is the local host).
> - The hostnames "localhost" and "localhost.localdomain" (as well as any hostname ending in ".localhost" or ".localhost.localdomain") are
>     resolved to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1.
> - The hostname "_gateway" is resolved to all current default routing gateway addresses, ordered by their metric. This assigns a stable
>     hostname to the current gateway, useful for referencing it
>     independently of the current network configuration state.
> - The mappings defined in /etc/hosts are resolved to their configured addresses and back, but they will not affect lookups for non-address
>     types (like MX).

According to documentation for `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and the [related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442599/85039), you can edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` to have specific domain resolved by your local DNS sever (on Ubuntu you have dnsmasq, [example](https://askubuntu.com/a/918161/295286)), or add `ReadEtcHosts=` to let the service actually use the file.

You can also disable the service. See [How to disable systemd-resolved in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/907246/295286)

---

According to a [Fedora forum thread](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?289522-Why-is-etc-hosts-getting-overwritten) the issue could also relate to Network Manager service. For Ubuntu servers, cloud-init could also be the cause of the issue according to the [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+bug/890501)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I disabled systemd-resolved per the instructions however that doesnt fix the issue, the hosts file is still being reset.   
As for that bug you linked, I dont think that is what is going on here as I am pointing to another IP on my LAN, not using 127.0.0.1