# Can't run Dnsmasq via command line

Tags: dns, dhcp, dnsmasq

I am unable to install Dnsmasq via command line, this error is shown :
Package dnsmasq is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from a nother source.
However the following packages replace it : dnsmasq-base.
E: Package 'dnsmasq' has no installation candidate.

Searching in the Ubuntu store, I can find and install It, but I don't find the dnsmasq.conf file in /etc/... Besides, typing
apt list *dns*
does not show dnsmasq at all, only dnsmasq-base.

Moreover, if I type :
sudo dnsmasq
Then, I got an other error message :
dnsmasq : failed to create listening socket for port 53: address already in use

I am on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and only want to set up a DHCP and DNS server to bypass the loopback restriction of my actual internet provider... I have already tried many things such as disabling dnsmasq-base but did not work...

Comment: You probably have `systemd-resolved` installed as a replacement for `dnsmasq`. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-dnsmasq-and-systemd-resolved) about how to avoid conflicts.

Comment: See this as it may help to start : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032450/how-to-add-dnsmasq-and-keep-systemd-resolved-18-04

Comment: I can't even install dnsmasq on my PC but thank for helping !