# NetworkManager not updating /var/run/networkmanager/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, ethernet

My NetworkManager is not writing to `/var/run/networkmanager/resolv.conf` and [NetworkManager not populating resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137037/) is not the answer to my situation, because I don't use `resolvconf`. More details below:

I switched managing my ethernet from `/etc/network/interfaces` to NetworkManager, which somehow never writes to `/var/run/networkmanager/resolv.conf`:

```
$ nmcli d  
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION  
eth0    ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --          

$ ls /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
ls: cannot access '/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf': No such file or directory

$ ls /var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf
ls: cannot access '/var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf': No such file or directory
```

That never bothered me when I'm using `/etc/network/interfaces`, but now that I'm using NetworkManager, I need it to update my `resolv.conf`.

Here is my `NetworkManager.conf`:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Some answers say I should have `dns=dnsmasq` in there, but some say I should not. All in all, I'm still confused how to have NetworkManager updating `/var/run/networkmanager/resolv.conf`.

Update, further info:

```
$ resolvectl status | grep DNS
-su: resolvectl: command not found

$ dpkg -l '*dns*' | grep 'ii *dns'
ii  dns-root-data  2018013001   all          DNS root data including root zone
ii  dnsmasq        2.79-1       all          Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/
ii  dnsmasq-base   2.79-1       amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/
ii  dnsutils       1:9.11.3+dfs amd64        Clients provided with BIND

$ dpkg -l '*resolv*' | grep ii || echo no resolvconf
no resolvconf

$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 79 2019-03-03 18:42 /etc/resolv.conf

$ host 8.8.8.8 
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-public-dns-a.google.com.

$ host www.ebay.com
www.ebay.com is an alias for slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net has address 104.93.181.25

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Update2.

- This is not a vanilla Ubuntu installation, but my customized installation from fresh (not an upgrade from previous version). I remove `resolvconf` myself, because I was using `/etc/network/interfaces`, and didn't want my `/etc/resolv.conf` to be changing all the time. Maybe that's the culprit and NetworkManager can't work without `resolvconf`?
- My full intention is to "[Replace systemd-resolved with dnsmasq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122641/)" (which I practiced using 18.04 LiveCD, which has the `resolvconf`), and use it for my LAN DNS server. Em, maybe in that case I don't need NetworkManager changing my `/etc/resolv.conf` all the time.

Anyway, here are the info for further investigation:

```
$ dpkg -l '*resolv*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  resolvconf     <none>       <none>       (no description available)

$ cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
cat: /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf: No such file or directory

$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
. . . 
nameserver 64.71.255.204
nameserver 64.71.255.198
search hitronhub.home

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.11/24, 192.168.0.10/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1

$ ps auxc | grep resolv
systemd+ 23890  0.0  0.0  70608  1520 ?        Ss   Mar01   0:00 systemd-resolve

$ sudo lsof -i tcp:53
COMMAND     PID            USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r 23890 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4 47127798      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   29822         dnsmasq    5u  IPv4 47935969      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   29822         dnsmasq    7u  IPv4 47935971      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.11:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   29822         dnsmasq    9u  IPv4 47935973      0t0  TCP localhost.myhost.org:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   29822         dnsmasq   11u  IPv6 47935975      0t0  TCP [fe80::xxxx]:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   29822         dnsmasq   13u  IPv6 47935977      0t0  TCP [2607:fea8:xxxx]:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   29822         dnsmasq   15u  IPv6 47935979      0t0  TCP [fd00:xxxx]:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   29822         dnsmasq   17u  IPv6 47935981      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:domain (LISTEN)
```

Comment: I am not surprised that a 2012 post is no longer effective. Please edit your question to add the result of: `resolvectl status | grep DNS` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *dns* | grep ii` and `dpkg -l *resolv* | grep ii` and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `host 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Thanks @chili555, I got `resolvectl: command not found` for that.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Is your 18.04 an upgrade, or a clean install? Show me `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and `cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `ps auxc | grep resolv`. Have you made any modifications to any network software here? Uninstalled something? Show this command again... with no modifications... `dpkg -l *resolv*`, Why no resolvconf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No wonder I said "*Something is wrong here*". In your "*customization*", you've kind of made an unnecessary mess of things. Stop trying to defeat the system. Sorry.

---

In `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` you've combined NetworkManager and netplan script. Your .yaml file should look like this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

This information belongs in NetworkManager GUI connection profile, or in `/etc/network/interfaces`, in NetworkManager speak... not netplan speak...

```
ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.11/24, 192.168.0.10/24] (why two addresses?)
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
```

---

- reinstall `resolvconf`
- reset `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink

  - see below for link information
  - and don't manually edit this file
- edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (see below for instructions)
- remove dns=dnsmasq from `/etc/network/interfaces`
- remove `dnsmasq*` **unless you can explain why you need it**

---

**Regarding `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`...**

Do a `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and look for `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`, and if both are running, you need to disable the DNS part of `systemd-resolved` by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

then restart systemd-resolve and dnsmasq, or reboot.

**You MAY need to reset the symlink that is /etc/resolv.conf** (*if dnsmasq is not running*)...

`sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.OLD` # save the old symlink

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # create new symlink

**Note**: original symlink is...

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Thanks a lot heynnema, I wasn't messing up my system, I was just trying to get what I want based on all sorts of (weird/out-dated) answers I found from the internet. :-) Glad to find askubuntu to be the prefect place for my weird questions. Thanks at lot for all your helps!

Comment: +1 for "Stop trying to defeat the system."

Comment: @chili555 that's funny... giggle.