# systemd starts dnsmasq before starting network manager?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, systemd, dnsmasq

Looks to me that my systemd starts dnsmasq before starting network manager. How can I confirm this? How can I force systemd starts dnsmasq after starting network manager?

Reason behind this is, as explained in [NetworkManager not updating /var/run/networkmanager/resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122836/),

- I'm using dnsmasq as my LAN DNS server, and
- I defined my two IP addresses in NetworkManager.

When my system started my dnsmasq is not working, and I found that the reason is it is not listening to my two IP addresses at all. Only after restarting it, it started to listen to my two IP addresses:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:53
COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r 544 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  18667      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   793         dnsmasq    5u  IPv4  23719      0t0  TCP localhost.my.box.name:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   793         dnsmasq    7u  IPv6  23721      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:domain (LISTEN)

/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
[ ok ] Restarting dnsmasq (via systemctl): dnsmasq.service.

$ lsof -i tcp:53
COMMAND     PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r   544 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  18667      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   17895         dnsmasq    5u  IPv4 601091      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   17895         dnsmasq    7u  IPv4 601093      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.11:domain (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   17895         dnsmasq    9u  IPv4 601095      0t0  TCP localhost...

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

# my systemd is not the latest but I think that shouldn't matter:
$ apt-cache policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.9
  Version table:
     237-3ubuntu10.9 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Update**:

@heynnema, Thanks for the `systemd-analyze --no-pager blame`, I've confirmed that the start order is as expected

> NetworkManager -> systemd-resolved -> dnsmasq.

So indeed, it is about dnsmasq and systemd-resolved stepping on each others toes. I've added `DNSStubListener=no` since. I have two following up questions now.

- Why it is OK for dnsmasq `restart` to work just fine? Its working fine gave me the impression that it is OK to have them both working.
- Actually, I used `systemctl stop systemd-resolved` and `systemctl disable systemd-resolved` to completely disable systemd-resolved, instead of just stopping its listener previously. I don't know why it does not persist over reboot.

Comment: First verify the start order with `systemd-analyze --no-pager blame` - You seem to believe that the issue you dont describe comes from the start order. Maybe it just related to some misconfiguration?... Anyway, you can try to modify start order (ie: services/units dependencies) according to the freedesktop reference http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: As I answered in your TWO prior questions regarding your network configuration... you have to disable systemd-resolved `DNSStubListener=no` when also running dnsmasq. If you don't want to do that, dnsmasq and systemd-resolved WILL step on each others toes. Is there some reason why you don't seem to want to do this?

Comment: @heynnema, thanks for helping, please see my updated OP.

Comment: I read your update. And no... you don't "added DNSStubListener=no" to anything, you just edit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf. And no... you don't try and systemctl stop/disable systemd-resolved. You just need to follow my instructions and then leave it alone. Sorry if I sound a little miffed... this is the third time I'm recommending this, and that you stop trying to defeat the system. It was designed to work as it is... not some "customized" vision in your head. Sorry...

Comment: Sorry to be dense @heynnema, hmm... in my defense, I think the problem is that the question "[Replace systemd-resolved with dnsmasq](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122641/)" was not fully answered, as I've explained better to "_list the correct steps on how to replace systemd-resolved with dnsmasq, instead of correcting what I've been doing wrong_". So I have to rely on steps in https://askubuntu.com/questions/898605/ to cover the missing pieces, and systemctl stop/disable systemd-resolved was the accepted answer. I was not dong some "customized" vision in my head but following instructions.

Comment: Besides, adding "DNSStubListener=no" to the end of ***unmodified*** /etc/systemd/resolved.conf would have the same effect as your saying of changing the "#DNSStubListener=yes", isn't it?

Comment: Yes, adding "DNSStubListener=no" instead of just uncommenting the existing line in the file is effectively the same... but then changing it back again later? I just don't understand your burning desire to stop systemd-reolved from running, and uninstalling resolvconf, etc. Left alone, with one edit, they can all run together... and still accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do... without breaking stuff.

Comment: No, I put "DNSStubListener=no" in and will not change it back. And again I was just following the steps which were accepted as the answer from [How to disable systemd-resolved and resolve DNS with dnsmasq?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898605/). Anyway, thanks again for all your helps @heynnema. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but only on 16.04 systems updated to 18.04. I am also using dnsmasq as my LAN DNS and DHCP server.
On a freshly installed 18.04, it is working out of the box, without having to modify `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (DNSStubListener).

Answer (score 0):

Unresolved [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1777094) in ***Ubuntu 18.04***.  I'll show you how I worked around it.  Maybe others have a more elegant solution, but I'll start the ball rolling with my own.

The problem lives in the **[Unit]** section in the `After=` directive which must be modified as follows to raise ***dnsmasq.service*** unbroken on boot:

```
sed -i 's/After=network.target/After=NetworkManager-wait-online.service/' /lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
```

When testing I initially tried `After=NetworkManager.service` which seemed a sensible choice. But after a reboot ***dnsmasq*** was still rising-up broken on boot.  So I did:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

And found `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` started even later. That's how I found the appropriate relative order in which to raise ***dnsmasq.service***.  HTH you if you've stumbled onto this issue-