# Is resolvconf hard-coded its nameserver setting?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, resolv.conf, resolvconf

First of all, this is not a duplicate of [How do I include lines in resolv.conf that won't get lost on reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154), as

A) It has not been working since 14.04. See the comment:

> In 14.04 this answer did nothing for me. – Jay Sullivan Jun 30 '14

B) The answer there is to use `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file, but this question asks exactly why `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file is not working.

Following up on [Use dnsmasq as system DNS service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122641/), I installed `resolvconf` as per the latest reply/answer, however, I found that, the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file, which should be use to preset `nameserver` values as per all documents that I read, is not doing what is advertised/documented. Here is what the man page says:

> **/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base**
>                 File  containing  basic resolver information.  The lines in this
>                 file are included in the resolver configuration file  even  when
>                 no interfaces are configured.

However I found that, whatever info I put into the `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file, they would never show up in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

So just to confirm, is there any way to properly configured `nameserver` of `/etc/resolv.conf` for `resolvconf`?

So far my conclusion is that

- the `127.0.0.1` is hard-coded for `resolvconf` and there is no way to overwrite it.
- the only way is to supersede it in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, producing two `nameserver`s in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. One valid and the other invalid (`127.0.0.1`).

And I truly hope that I'm wrong.

P.S. this is LUbuntu 18.04.2:

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: using 18.04 desktop version ? if so, you must look at systemd.resolved and networkmanager too

Comment: I'm still confused what are you trying to do? You want to change the `nameserver` in *resolv.conf* ?

Comment: Exactly @JoKeR. To ***change*** the default `127.0.0.1` to a valid one.

Comment: what happens if you write `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` and enter it manually and save it.

Comment: It then get overwritten all the time. Do a search then you'll know, @JoKeR.

Comment: The network automatically overwrites it with the correct dns that is assigned by your system if you delete the content of `resolv.conf` and input lets say `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` it will work but once you reload Network Manger it will apply your Network dns which your system uses. In my case my dns gets overwritten by my VPN that I use because that is a dns it relies on.

Comment: Yes, exactly, your manual input will work, but once you reload Network Manger, or machine get started, it'll got the wrong value (127.0.0.1) again, @JoKeR. I.e., I'm providing my own DNS, so the hard-coded 127.0.0.1 will always be wrong for me, albeit it might be the correct dns for you. See my linked question in OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include lines in resolv.conf that won't get lost on reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot)

Comment: @JoKeR, The answer there is to use `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file, but this question asks exactly why `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file is not working.

Comment: there are a couple of working examples

Comment: but none of them answer the question why /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base file is not working, which is what this question is for.