# How to make persistent changes to /etc/resolv.conf Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, dns, 18.10, resolv.conf

My resolv.conf file has 'nameserver 127.0.0.53'.
I need to replace it with different value or add another nameserver.

I erased symlink, replaced it with file. 
Now it is managed by Network Manager,
but 127.0.0.53 is restored upon reboot.

I need to keep changes, I made.

If I configure network interface in 'interfaces' file,
it becomes 'UNMANAGED' in Network Manager. It's configuration has no effect, though.

This question is related [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125228/ubuntu-18-10-wifi-login-problem?noredirect=1#comment1862194_1125228).

Guys, If it is not so much trouble, will you, please, read.

Before I perform any 'ping' or 'host', I have to get through that LOGIN procedure.

My main problem is there. What I am trying to do here is to create a kind of work around.

Adding ANY nameserver except 127.0.0.53 or 0.0.0.0 into resolv.conf makes that thing working.
Network DNS is 192.168.11.1. I inserted 192.168.0.1 and it worked. **You name it - it goes.** But changing settings in Network Manager has no effect at all.

@heynnema, I did those settings in IPV4 tab before I rose the question, but unfortunately, they did not work.
/etc/network/interfaces file is intact,
UBUNTU 18.10 is clean installed.
I edited the file for the sake of creating a router in DEBIAN, and I saw how it worked. I do not want it to be the same way here.

@Marmayogi my DNS is 192.168.11.1, the same one is in /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. I was surprised to see it there.

Yes, @Marmayogi, my goal is to get that screen.
On UNITY 18.04 this file does not exist, but it does not change much.

```
/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
```

---

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:ae:c5:35:85:e6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:5d:60:c5:91:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

---

```
systemd-resolve --status wlp3s0
Link 3 (wlp3s0)
  Current Scopes: DNS
   LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
DNSOverTLS setting: no
    DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
Current DNS Server: 192.168.11.1
     DNS Servers: 192.168.11.1
      DNS Domain: ~.
                  crew.local
```

Yes @Marmayogi, this is the only thing I want working for now. This solution seems aukward to me, though. There was a symlink, as you can see in other post. I removed it, hoping that I would get things working for me.

@Marmayogi, you did a Great job, creating that step by step instruction.

**Your solution is GENIUS, not decent!**

I tested. Login successful, internet works.

@heynnema,
  `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` does not exist on UBUNTU 18.10.
What would you advise in this situation?

System is installed clean from ISO, downloaded from UBUNTU.COM.

Comment: What is your default nameserver @igor at present? What is your network adapter? You are NOT directly allowed to edit `/etc/resolv.conf`! you may have to symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` which would contain your default nameserver. Please check.

Comment: See the man page for it. It lists the sources on how resolv.conf is recreated. From memory:  dhclient, networkmanager, dnsmasq.

Comment: @Marmayogi my DNS is 192.168.11.1, the same one is in /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. Will you, please, read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125228/ubuntu-18-10-does-not-display-login-page-for-wifi-network-not-captiva?noredirect=1#comment1862194_1125228). This is my post, which is the reason I need those changes in resolv.conf. I do not have connection to the network when nameserver is set to 127.0.0.53.

Comment: After performing my answer, edit your question and show me `host www.ebay.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Try `ip link show` command and find out your Wi-Fi adapter 'state up' and running. Note down you WiFi adpter name such as `wlp5s0`. Does the command `systemd-resolve --status wlp5s0` display your default dns server?  (Please don't forget to replace `wlp5s0` with your own wifi adapter name). What I understand @Igor is your primary focus is getting `login` screen for your Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: Is your `/etc/netplan/.yaml` file configured? If it is so, then the login screen for your Wi-Fi connection may not display. @Igor, please check.

Comment: My understanding is that you don't have a Wi-Fi connection to the network whenever nameserver is set to 127.0.0.53. i.e. whenever `/etc/resolve.conf` contains 127.0.0.53. However, what prevented you from symlinking `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` persistently through the command `ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolve.conf`? Because `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` always contains you default nameserver. Do you have any extra requirements beyond accepting this symlink solution?  I like to comprehend not only your problem @Igor, but also your requirement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am reproducing section **"1.11.2. Configure /etc/resolv.conf file"** from my answer **Part-I Preinstallation**: [How to install Oracle 18c (Enterprise Edition) on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121649/how-to-install-oracle-18c-enterprise-edition-on-ubuntu-18-04/1122486#1122486)

To display what network interfaces are available in the system, issue the following command:

`$ ip link show`

[image]
`Figure-39: The WiFi network adapter wlp5s0 is active, up and running.`

Network configuration file `/etc/netplan/.yaml` should be checked for configuration details. To display the contents of the file, issue the following command:

`$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

[image]
`Figure-40: Network Manager file 01-network-manager-all.yaml is not configured yet.`

Find out whether `/etc/resolv.conf` is a static file or `symlink` by the following command:

`$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`

[image]
`Figure-41: File /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink pointing to stub file 'stub-resolv.conf'.`

In fact, @igor, the symlink what you removed from **other post** was really the link to stub file `stub-resolv.conf`.

After severed the symlink between `/etc/resolv.conf` and `stub-resolv.conf` which carried  the nameserver `127.0.0.53`,  `/etc/resolv.conf` was left alone and it was you who made `/etc/resolv.conf` as a static file!

The fact is, @Igor, you were not really offered any solution by that act of severance.

Now, display contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` by the command:

`$ cat /etc/resolv.conf`
[image]
`Figure-42: The contents of symlink '/etc/resolv.conf' having 127.0.0.53 as nameserver.`

The dns shown by `/etc/resolv.conf`, is `127.0.0.53` but not the default nameserver configured for `dhcp`.

Issue the following command to find out the default dns server:

`$ systemd-resolve --status wlp5s0`

[image]
`Figure-43: The default DNS server for WiFi network adapter is 192.168.43.1.`

Display contents of `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, by the command:

`$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

[image]
`Figure-44: The contents of '/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf' indicating default nameserver.`

From figure-44, you can observe that `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` is the one which really is carrying the default name server `192.168.43.1`.

Issue the following command to change the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf` to point default dns server `192.168.43.1` instead of `127.0.0.53`.

```
$ sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
```

[image]
`Figure-45: File /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink pointing to default nameserver.`

After setting up sysmlink as shown in figure-45, you must make sure that your Wi-Fi is connected, up and running, by issuing the following command:

`$ nmcli device`

[image]
`Figure-45-a: Wi-Fi network interface adapter 'wlp5s0' is connected, up and running.`

**Conclusion:**

Under the circumstances, the symlink is the not only best answer you got but also a decent and acceptable solution.

Comment: is there any way to inform UBUNTU team about this situation? It is sertainly not normal.

Comment: This is how things are @Igor. During my attempt to `install Oracle 18c`, I had faced plenty of problems with 127.0.0.53 and finally solved using this simple symlink solution. Even Centos 7, you will find similar issues. However, what exactly is to complain with Ubuntu team? What is in your mind?

Comment: Last UBUNTU I tried was 15. It worked well. I tested it on this network as well - no problems. Debian 8.6 & 9.8 work fine. They have different way of networking handling. I am pretty sure, that when I install the system, I must be able to use networking **from the box**, but not looking for the problem solution. Do you agree, @Marmayogi? Whatever people say of Microsoft, but nobody would ever have this kind of issue.

Comment: Two points... the `systemd-resolve --status` command already showed the correct DNS server, your original symlink used `stub-resolv.conf`, and re-symlinking to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` also showed the correct DNS server... the problem with your symlink is that you may have problems with VPN and DNS leaks. Best to use the symlink in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thank you. It is not so convenient, though. Actually when setting up VPN it is necessary to alter network configuration. This is not my case now. I needed to get UBUNTU on the internet. Another thing is I do not have `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` file on my system. It is UBUNTU 18.10

Answer (score 5):

1. First, remove your edits from `/etc/network/interfaces`.
2. Next, we delete your static `/etc/resolv.conf` file and replace it with the original symlink.

   In `terminal`:

   `cd /etc` # change directory

   `sudo rm -i resolv.conf` # delete static file

   `sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate symlink

   Now DO NOT manually edit this file!
3. Finally, set your DNS servers here.

   Set `DNS Automatic` to OFF. Enter comma-separated DNS IP addresses.

   [image: screenshot]

Comment: @Igor Did you remove your edits from `/etc/network/interfaces`? Did you enter the values that I've circled in RED? Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the IPv4 tab so I can see your settings.

Comment: It looks like the image has been blocked. I will try to find a way to open. I did edit 'interfaces' file and saw the results. But it is original now. OS is clean installed.

Comment: this happened to work better `sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`. There is no need to change network configuration manually. I have it already working.

Comment: @Igor but you may have a problem if you're going to use VPN.

Comment: Thank you @heynnema, I did not know that. In case I have  a problem, I will go your way.

Comment: My machine is headless.  How do I turn this off from the shell?  Thanks! (the setting in the second circle of your image)

Comment: @ErikBennett Please start a new question for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

td;dr

`/etc/resolv.conf` should not be edited by users

```
> cat /etc/resolv.conf # Ubutnu 18
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
```

Network Manger has changed to "netplan" in Ubuntu 18
netplan's tool for managing DNS is `systemd-resolve`

#### On the fly configuration

1. Check

   ```
   sudo systemd-resolve  --status eth0
   ```

   eth0  is your interface

   if there were no DNS servers, set it
2. Set

   ```
   sudo systemd-resolve  --interface eth0 --set-dns 1.1.1.1
   ```

   (you can add more using multiple --set-dns option)

#### for persistent configuration

Take a look at

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

And example of a `yaml` file

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.121.199/24
      gateway4: 192.168.121.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

#### See more

1. [how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04/)
2. [netplan](https://netplan.io/)

Also you can install "resolveconf" which is simpler plus none of these are best, if you are managing a Server.

For Server take a look at FreeBSD tool: `relayd` or PowerDNS tool: `dnsdist`.

Answer (score 0):

I used resolv.conf to set *nameserver* and *search* because of **VPN** but it wasn't right solution even before Ubuntu 18 (because it is not used only for VPN but for all connections). Better solution is [using openvpn-systemd-resolved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032476/ubuntu-18-04-no-dns-resolution-when-connected-to-openvpn/1036209) and this solution works for me.