# I can not open a Wifi with captive portal

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, dns

There is a public Wifi which I am unable to use, because I cannot get to the captive portal where i can put the user name and password. i can do that from my phone but not from my Ubuntu 18.04.3

I tried the solutions which are written here:
[Cannot reach public WIFI login page in Ubuntu 18.04 Captive Portal Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046321/cannot-reach-public-wifi-login-page-in-ubuntu-18-04-captive-portal-issue)
but still it is not working. any help please.

Comment: Here is how i did with a captive portal: connect ot public wifi then visit a webpgae that has NO SSL, then it redirects to the login page of the captive portal. A non ssl page:  http://sebl69.free.fr/ (not my site)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot reach public WIFI login page in Ubuntu 18.04 Captive Portal Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046321/cannot-reach-public-wifi-login-page-in-ubuntu-18-04-captive-portal-issue)