# How to make captive portal forget my laptop so I can sign in again?

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm at a hotel and have wifi; I signed in with the usual captive portal kind of setup for the hotel's free wifi tier.

I later got a code for their premium wifi -- but I can't seem to retrigger the captive portal so I can get the network to put me on the premium tier.

Is there anything I can do to make the network forget my computer and go through the captive portal again? Since initial sign-in, I haven't had to go through the captive portal so the system seems to remember me.

Comment: Are you sure it's a server side problem? Otherwise, check if you can manually trigger a captive portal in your browser, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046321/cannot-reach-public-wifi-login-page-in-ubuntu-18-04-captive-portal-issue

Comment: Disconnect from the Hotel's WiFi. Reboot. Reconnect.

Comment: None of those are working for me. :(  Any other ideas?