Ubuntu won't respond to captive portal. What is the fix?
I can't access the internet from the campus network as it now requires access via a captive portal where you agree to terms and conditions.
In Windows/Mac, a web browser will pop up so that you can accept the terms and proceed to use the internet.
How can I fix Ubuntu, so that it knows to do this.
When I try to access the network it throws a general error "Sorry, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error" which I send to Ubuntu.
Executable Path: /user/libexec/gnome-shell-portal-helper
Package: gnome-shell 46.0-0ubuntu5
Problem Type: Crash
...


hi @user27421491 try a solution provided by this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1053610/928088 and see if it works for you. If it doesn't, you can go through other answers from the same thread. Thanks

This question is similar to: Cannot reach public WIFI login page in Ubuntu 18.04 Captive Portal Issue. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
