# sudo takes long time to prompt password

Tags: 20.04, sudo

I am facing little issue in sudo command.
Whatever I try with `sudo` command it takes huge time to prompt password.

can anyone please tell me what might be the case.
commands like

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo systemctl start mongod
sudo systemctl start redis
```

Comment: Define "huge time".

Comment: password prompt used to come in 1ms, now it's taking approximately 10 seconds. I don't know the exact time, it's taking.

Comment: LOL 10 secs is a huge time.

Comment: haha, but is there any way to know this, why it's taking little time.

Comment: It *may* be related to hostname resolution - see for example [Terminal command with sudo takes a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322514/terminal-command-with-sudo-takes-a-long-time). Have you made any changes to hostname / hosts / nsswitch?

Comment: no, I haven't done any change.

Comment: @abinaspatra Maybe your DNS server(s) did stop working?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your hostname is not in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Find your hostname with one of below commands in terminal:

`$ hostname`

or

`$ hostnamectl | grep -i "static hostname"`

and then open your file with typing:

`$ sudo vim /etc/hosts`

and write below line in it and save it:

`127.0.0.1 YourHostName`