# sudo command execution slown down on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04

The sudo command execution was working fine until a few days ago, and it started working slow. When I run a sudo command in the terminal, it does not work faster. It takes a break of a few seconds to ask for the password.

If the password is already entered in the terminal, executing the command will take a bit of a delay. How do I make it faster? I am not getting a reason why it slows down. My disk space where ubuntu is installed is 45GB free.

[image]

**Update**

My hostname is already there in the said file
[image: terminal image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.1.1?

Comment: @FarhadKia Thanks. I just updated it. I don't know much about it why it was changed. I have changed it as you said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is occurring because your hostname is not in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Type

```
hostname
```

in your terminal. That will tell you what your hostname is.

Next, type:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and add:

```
127.0.0.1 yourhostname
```

then save - and you are done! Sudo should be fast now!

[thanks to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/458057/160531)